# Using the structure "by + time expression + past perfect" to describe a graph

Tags: past-perfect

Is the structure "by + time expression + past perfect" suitable for describing a graph regarding an event that we cannot exclusively say that it had happened before the specified time expression (based on the information in the graph)?

For example, can we write the following sentence regarding the following graph?

> 1. Expenditure on food ranked first among all categories in 1968. By 2018, however, it had dropped to the third rank.

[image]

Is it not poor English mainly because we use this structure to indicate that something had happened in an indefinite time before the specific time expression?

For comparison, we can consider the following sentence which seems less controversial:

> 2. Expenditure on food ranked first among all categories in 1968. In 2018, however, it dropped to the third rank.

---

To justify my question, I should mention that I have seen this usage of this structure in authentic English books. For example, on the page 120 of the book "Cambridge Vocabulary For Ielts With Answers", the following sentence is suggested for the following graph, and I doubt whether its a correct sentence or not because the black line does not intersect the red line at any time sooner than 2005.

> 3. Fortunately, recycling has gradually increased and by 2005 it had again reached the same figure as in 1990.

[image]

Comment: It depends on context. If it makes sense to view the event as before other past events, past perfect is fine. In other situations it'll be a judgement call. You need to look at the larger context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “By” is at least as good, and I would say preferable to, “in” in this context.

The reason is the specifics of the graph. It shows only data for two time points — 1968 and 2018. It is scientifically **correct** to say:

> **In** 1968 expenditure on food ranked…, whereas **in** 2018 it ranked …

However the poster’s use of **in** is **incorrect** scientifically when he writes:

> **In** 2018 it *dropped* to…

This because of the use of “dropped” (an action) rather than “ranked” (a description). We do not know when — between 1968 and 2018 — the drop occurred, whereas this sentence suggests it occurred in 2018 and not before — a completely unjustified assertion.

That is presumably why the writer used **by**. He was acknowledging the fact that the data do not indicate when the change occurred. His form of words is linguistically and scientifically correct (and common in academic writing).

It perhaps possible to use **in** to express the idea, but only if we change the tense of the poster’s suggestion:

> In 2018 it **had** dropped off…

But **by** is better — by a long chalk.

Comment: Thanks reason of the usage of past perfect in the first example is now clear for me. But what about the second example? In that line graph it is clear that until 2005 it didn't reach the same figure as in 1990.

Comment: @alizera — There's nothing wrong with it, but there 'in' would be equally valid. It's just a question of emphasis or style. Using 'in' puts the emphasis on 2005, using 'by' allows reflection on the 15 years that it took until it had bounced back.